# My 'spinner' animation stops

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, animation, loading

I have a simple 'Progress' class which controls my spinning dots and a progress bar.
The problem is that my dots sometimes stop animating during loading my components. Here's my code:

```
    protected static const CONST_DOTS_ANIM_DELAY = 85;
    protected var m_tDotsAnimTimer:Timer;

    m_tDotsAnimTimer = new Timer( CONST_DOTS_ANIM_DELAY );
    m_tDotsAnimTimer.addEventListener(TimerEvent.TIMER, DotsAnimHandler);


    public function DotsAnimHandler(event:Event):void
    {
        mcSpinnerDots["mcFadeDot"+m_nCurrentDot].gotoAndPlay( 2 );
        m_nCurrentDot++;
        if( m_nCurrentDot == 8 )
        {
            m_nCurrentDot = 0;
        }
    }


    public function ShowSpinner():void
    {
        mcSpinnerDots.visible = true;
        m_tDotsAnimTimer.start();
        visible = true;
    }
```

With Thanks :)

Answer (score 1):

I have a strong feeling that on your handler you call to a non-existing dot and you can't see it well because you call it though [].

Trace `trace(mcSpinnerDots["mcFadeDot"+m_nCurrentDot])` on the first line of your handler and see if it returns a value of your dot.

You can also optimize the counter with following line of code

```
m_nCurrentDot = (m_nCurrentDot + 1) % 9; // range from 0 to 8
```

instead of

```
m_nCurrentDot++;
if( m_nCurrentDot == 8 )
{
   m_nCurrentDot = 0;
}
```

It will both work faster and look better.

Hope that helps!

Comment: Just because it is rarely taught in classes or tutorials, I would like to add that that optimization (n % t) is called modulus and is a very fast way to look for left-overs

Answer (score 0):

creative magic has some good suggestions, but if you have a cycling animation with 8 dots, instead of having eight assets on the stage and mange them all separately, make them into one mc.  That revokes the need of a timer